# Finite elements discretization for evolution problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, parabolic-pde, numerical-calculus

we have the following problem:
$$
u_t +u u_x - \nu u_{xx} = f(x,t); \ x \in \mathbb{R}, t \in [0,T]
$$
where $\nu > 0$, 
with the initial condition:
$$
u(x,0)= g(x),
$$
and boundary conditions:
$$
u(0,t)= r_1(x), \ u(1,t)=r_2(x).
$$

I want to apply finite difference on time and finite elements $P_2$ in space to discretize this problem and obtain an aproximate solution.

I try this:

Firts, we linearize the problem using a simple fixed point method. We introduce a $nith =0$ and consider the linear problem

$$
u_t +nith * u_x - \nu u_{xx} = f(x,t); \ x \in \mathbb{R}, t \in [0,T]
$$
then we discritize this problem in time and space, we obtain $u_h$ and we pu $nith=u_h$ then we repete the discretisation.

Concerning the discretization, we discretize in time, then we write 
$$
\partial_t u_h = \dfrac{u_h - U_\mathrm{old}}{dt},
$$
where $dt$ is the step time discretisation.
My questions are:

1. What's the variational formulation associated to this problem?
2. What's the space of approximation using to apply the finite elements? And what's the linear problem $K_h u_h =b_h$ associated?

Best regards.